# Coffee script event not firing - why not?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I cannot seem to get a coffee script even firing. My code is below - and i hope it will help someone in future.

**Question: Why isn't the coffee script firing?**

**what am i trying to do**

- I'm trying to create a dynamic selection menu, like in Ryan Bates'
  railcasts:
  http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised?view=comments
- I'm trying to create three selection menus. First the user selects the client, then the project, then the building. A client has many projects which has many buildings. Obviously we want to limit user choices otherwise they'd have to choose from over 100 buildings if these results weren't filtered by first selecting the client and then project.

**Here is my coffeescript:**

```
    ## This bit works fine
    jQuery ->
      projects = $('#project_id').html()                        #Gets the project drop down elements
      $('#client_id').change ->                                 #If we change our client selection then:
        client = $('#client_id :selected').text()               # OBtain the client 
        options = $(projects).filter("optgroup[label='#{client}']").html() #Filter all projects by client
        if options
          $('#project_id').html(options)                      # redraw the drop down menu to show only projects by a specific client.
        else
          $('#project_id').empty()

    #This is not firing for some reason ---------------->
      $('#project_id').change -> 
        alert('hello')
        buildings = $('#building_id').html()    
        project = $('#project_id :selected').text()   
        options1 = $(buildings).filter("optgroup[label='#{project}']").html()
        if options1
          $('#building_id').html(options1)
        else
          $('#building_id').empty()
```

**And here is my form:**

```
<%= form_for(@rate) do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/errors", object: @rate %>

  <fieldset>
    <ol>
      <li class="required">             
        <%= 'client_id included' %>
        <%= collection_select(:client, :client_id, Client.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, html_options = {:id => 'client_id'} ) %>                  
      </li>

      <li class="required">
        <%= "Now for the project" %>
        <%= grouped_collection_select :building, :project_id, Client.all, :projects, :name, :id, :name,   {include_blank: true}, html_options = {:id => 'project_id'} %>
      </li>

      <li class="required">
        <%= "Now for the building" %>
        <%= grouped_collection_select :rate, :building_id, Project.order(:name), :buildings, :name, :id, :name,   {include_blank: true}, html_options = {:id => 'building_id'} %>
      </li>

 <!-- The bits in the middle are more or less superfluous '-->

    </ol>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", rates_path, class: 'button' %>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

**HTML output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/buildings.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/buildings_users.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/clients.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/job_types.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/levels.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/projects.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/rates.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/scaffolds.self-d8a942e24537698777a64d6b68054e18e50999d296516c9493a2fd4e5d60af81.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-d885a0a66bd595c10edb24f8879f94e334d88be0730c4d7c7a7b57c731c09037.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.self-7311c6e43c663ee33d9337f66262109ff492bd7f4d6931ab91bf3e5d16996e4d.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.self-176b9819f30444d441e820bbccd3264fe57753aeafd54dec732b0dbc77129a2a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-e87806d0cf4489aeb1bb7288016024e8de67fd18db693fe026fe3907581e53cd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.self-f520d04a662abc3bbb379438d969df199552297a55b74651a9e2b33b775df3ed.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/cocoon.self-6874ad698cefd21cc1119b773550f61b5c1a60396460f015222af59293affe80.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/buildings.self-3459e57b18d5a1aa4a87df1e247d6e79661ece4c5393a0eaefe33c7aa2bbd4f7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/buildings_users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/clients.self-63aba6d2aaa54e15667299e2c02a9048af4b8ccc2a466875187772656308d251.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/job_types.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/levels.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/projects.self-9e4e52aed79a76394e24a14f669c14567fe2dd8743d9823305ca453005602d2c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/rates.self-3dc44bfaec2fed1ef3dcafb28d086bd17a05da66443bb3162dabb4be4f325d3b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-44dc72337fbefc4f8c73fc8781b922cf9e4f99f8d068e6563c3820851d9390f6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="1tcpiwfep0X1hhR+sZdr41Kn9djZfkDt/Mi+UAWO8Tatv73vzGSnR1DPR7ccUxtATBLxjOTNBA1LfFLO9mPMPg==" />
</head>
<body>
<header id="page-header">
  <div id="masthead">
    <h1><a href="/">Home Page</a></h1>
        <!--
    <nav>

      <p>
      </p>

    </nav>
        -->
  </div>
</header>

<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="container">
    <section id="sidebar">
      <aside id="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="clients">
      </li>
          <li class="create-client">
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>

    </section>
    <section id="content">
      <form class="new_rate" id="new_rate" action="/rates" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="ooJoSX4sk0TQ4ZxrqW24pxxQLBWXrcGL+A3J5jFZCo/Z6vwttZaTRnWoz6IEqcgEAuUoQaoehWtPuSV4wrQ3hw==" />


<fieldset>
    <ol>
            <li class="required">               
                    client_id included
                    <select id="client_id" name="client[client_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="2">Safeway Precast</option>
<option value="3">Bianco Precast</option></select>                  
            </li>

      <li class="required">
                    Select Project
                    <select id="project_id" name="building[project_id]"><option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="Safeway Precast"><option value="5">world map house</option>
<option value="7">project2</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Bianco Precast"><option value="6">Test1</option></optgroup></select>
            </li>

            <li class="required">
                    Now for the building
                    <select id="building_id" name="rate[building_id]"><option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="Test1"><option value="19">test2</option></optgroup><optgroup label="project2"></optgroup><optgroup label="world map house"><option value="14">Asdf</option>
<option value="15">351</option>
<option value="16">350</option>
<option value="17">350</option>
<option value="18">X</option></optgroup></select>
            </li>


      <li class="required">
        <label for="rate_rate">Rate</label>
        <input autofocus="autofocus" type="number" name="rate[rate]" id="rate_rate" />
      </li>
      <li class="required">
        <label for="rate_job_type">Job type</label>
        <select name="rate[job_type]" id="rate_job_type"><option value="1">Detailing Redraw</option>
<option value="2">Tracing</option>
<option value="3">Mark up Updation</option></select>
      </li>

      <li class="required">
        <label for="rate_note">Note</label>
        <textarea cols="80" rows="15" name="rate[note]" id="rate_note">
</textarea>
      </li>

<!-- and now let's try and dynamically select our building'-->

    </ol>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Rate" />
      <a class="button" href="/rates">Cancel</a>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>

    </section>
  </div>

</div>

<footer id="page-footer">
  <p>
    Copyright &copy; 2016 Advanced Bboi Productions
    <a href="http://www.tek1.com.au">Tek1</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    For invoicing purposes only.
  </p>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Any idea where the problem is? Any assistance much appreicated:

It is the third selection menu, see below, which refuses to be refined based on the selection menu choices made by the two menus preceding it, which is giving me grief. When a client is chosen, the next selection menu, projects, shows a refined menu based on which client is chosen. Now I need the next menu to be refined based on what project is chosen, but it's not doing that. Any assistance much appreciated. I will post code to the complete solution in any case, when I get it.

```
<select id="building_id" name="rate[building_id]"><option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="Test1"><option value="19">test2</option></optgroup><optgroup label="project2"></optgroup><optgroup label="world map house"><option value="14">Asdf</option>
<option value="15">351</option>
<option value="16">350</option>
<option value="17">350</option>
<option value="18">X</option></optgroup></select>
```

Comment: seems like too much symbolic params for me in building select: `Client.all, :projects, :name, :id, :name`. does it get filled by first jquery correctly? could you attach the bare html code generated by form aswell?

Comment: @twonegatives thank you the first two menus work perfectly fine - even the third works fine. When I select a client on the first selection menu, then the second menu, projects, is refined. But when I select a project - i want the third menu to also be refined. It's not being refined at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have three drop down menus. I want the second to be filtered by the selection made in the first menu, and i want the third to in turn be filtered by the selection made in the second (and by implication the first, indirectly). The problem that was occurring here is that when a client is selected (the first menu) then the projects menu gets filtered (i.e. the second menu), but this filtering process DOES NOT trigger a change event on the menu, which will subsequently filter the third menu. So I changed the code to force people to make a selection - because the initial selection is now blank.

here is my new code

```
jQuery ->
  projects = $('#project_id').html()
  $('#client_id').change ->
    client = $('#client_id :selected').text()     
    options = $(projects).filter("optgroup[label='#{client}']").html()
    $('#project_id option').remove()
    if options
        $('#project_id').html(options)
        $('#project_id').val('')        
    else
        $('#project_id').empty()

jQuery ->  
  buildings = $('#building_id').html()             # gets the buildings sub-sub-list elements
  $('#project_id').change ->                       # when the parent list changes then trigger:
      project = $('#project_id :selected').text()  # select what the parent project is
      options1 = $(buildings).filter("optgroup[label='#{project}']").html() # filter the buildings by parent
      $('#building_id option').remove()            #clears the building element 
      if options1        
        $('#building_id').html(options1)            # applies changes to selection based on parent
        $('#building_id').val('')        
      else
        $('#buidling_id').empty()                    #show nothing if empty
```